# Breadth First Search in O(log n)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph

Is it possible to find the destination from a source in O(log n) time using BFS (using min vertices traversed) in an undirected graph with loop and negative edges?

For ex:
You are given a simple connected graph G with N vertices and N edges (a simple graph is an un-directed graph that has no loops and no more than one edge between any two different vertices).
It is obvious that the graph G contains exactly one cycle and you can assume that the length of this cycle is odd (there are odd number of vertices in this cycle).
The vertices are numbered from 1 to N. Each edge is assigned a corresponding integer weight.
Your mission is to stimulate two types of queries :
Update query represented by f u v: change the sign of all the weights of the edges on the shortest path (you can see the definition of shortest path in this problem later on) from vertex u to vertex v.
Find query represented by ? u v: On the shortest path from vertex u to vertex v, find the (possibly empty) set of consecutive edges such that the sum of the weights is maximal. In other words, let's define the shortest path from u to v as a_1, a_2, ..., a_k (where a_1 = u and a_k = v). You have to find a_i and a_j such that i <= j and the sum of the weights of the edges of the path a_i, a_(i + 1), ..., a_j is as large as possible. You just have to find that sum.
The shortest path between two vertices u and v is the path connecting them with the minimal number of vertices. In this problem, it is obvious that there is only one shortest path between any pair of vertices of G.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you want a bit better. What do you mean by n? The number of nodes? What do you mean by 'find the destination'? Return a path? Maybe I'm misunderstanding but at the moment it seems dead obvious that what you're asking for is impossible, without some sort of preprocessing or constraint on the graphs.

Answer (score 5):

Let the `G` be a graph with Vertex set `V` and Edge set `E`. Then the time complexity in the worst case of the **Breadth First Search** (`BFS`) is `O(|V|+|E|)`. The time complexity is `O(|V|+|E|)`, because each vertex and edge is visited in the worst case. The complexity O(|E|) may vary between **O(|V|)** and **O(|V<sup>2</sup>|)**. In case of a sparse graph the complexity will be approximately **O(|V|)** and in case of a dense graph the complexity will be approximately **O(|V<sup>2</sup>|)**.

Answer (score 3):

BFS's time complexity is O(|E|).

O(logn) requires the graph to be sorted is some way.

Comment: can we first topologically sort the graph.